# How to create a named database host

Tags: mysql, replication, host, createuser

I am trying to set up a multi master `mysql` `replication` on two systems on a network. The two separate database servers are running `mysql` at `localhost`, How do I create a `replication` user for the `hosts` since they share the same name.

I could do this, but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

```
CREATE USER 'repl_user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';  // Server1
CREATE USER 'repl_user2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password2';  // Server2
```

I think something like this should do

```
CREATE USER 'repl_user1'@'server1.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';  // Server1
CREATE USER 'repl_user2'@'server2.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password2';  // Server2
```

but I don't know how to give the host a name.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you not use the same replication user on both instances?

Comment: I need a user with grant on replication on each instance with. My problem is how to reference the host, since they use the same name 'localhost'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IPs, ex:

```
CREATE USER 'repl_user1'@'192.168.1.101' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';  // Server1
CREATE USER 'repl_user2'@'192.168.1.102' IDENTIFIED BY 'password2';  // Server2
```

If you really want to use hostnames (and you don't already have some set up for your servers using DNS), just add them to your hosts file and reference those. Ex.:

/etc/hosts (server1)

```
127.0.0.1         localhost server1.local
192.168.1.101     server1.local
192.168.1.102     server2.local
```

/etc/hosts (server2)

```
127.0.0.1         localhost server2.local
192.168.1.101     server1.local
192.168.1.102     server2.local
```

Then set up the users:

```
CREATE USER 'repl_user1'@'server1.local' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';  // Server1
CREATE USER 'repl_user2'@'server2.local' IDENTIFIED BY 'password2';  // Server2
```

That should work so both servers receive connections from their own host and the other as well and map it to the correct users.